# variable javascript igual a contenido de archivo .json

Tags: javascript, json

Actualmente tengo un .js en que guardo un array json y lo igual a una variable

```
applications = {"apps": [
{ "app":"app1", "buzon":"buzon1" },
...
]};
```

Y mas abajo, en el mismo script utilizo la variable para trabajar con los datos del json. La idea es sacar el array del archivo .js para clarificar el codigo, guardarlo en otro fichero .json y desde el .js invocar su contenido e igualarllo a la variable. Espero haberme explicado.

Alguien puede indicarme como hacer esto?

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Estas usando algun framework o libreria en javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

creo que si quisieras sacar el array del archivo javascript sacrificarias el rendimiento, pues tuvieras que obtener los datos despues de haber cargado el script, pero lo que yo haria despues de haber sacado el arreglo y puesto en un archivo .json solamente quedaria obtenerlo con ajax, por ejemplo usando JQUERY seria:

```
$.ajax({
        // ruta relativa o absoluta de donde se encuentra el fichero o archivo
        url: "data.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // hacer tu logica ya teniendo la informacion del json
        },
        error: function(datas) {
            // logica si falla la carga
        }
});
```